# FedexDC PHP Label Script - Need To Save But Not Display PNG Image - FEDEX Direct Connect class

Tags: php, png, fedex

I'm using the fedexdc class to generate a shipping label for orders. The problem is that when I run the function on my application's page, it outputs all of the binary mess from the image that is create. I really just need it to save on the server (which it does) and not display on the page so that i can access it when I need to. Here's the function in the fedexdc class file. Any ideas on how I can do this?

```
function label($label_file=false) {
        $this->httpLabel =  $this->rHash[$this->image_key];
        if ($this->httpLabel = preg_replace('/%([0-9][0-9])/e', "chr(hexdec($1))", $this->httpLabel)) {
                $this->debug('separate binary image data');
                $this->debug('decoded binary label data');
        }
        if ($label_file) {
            $this->debug('label: trying to write out label to '. $label_file);
            $FH = fopen ($label_file, "w+b");
             if (!fwrite($FH, $this->httpLabel)) {
                $this->setError("Can't write to file $label_file");
                return false;
             }
             fclose($FH);
        } else {
            return $this->httpLabel;
        }

    }
```

Comment: This doesn't echo anything.  So there should be nothing echo-ed out unless you are doing it yourself or the `setError` function or `debug` function is echo-ing out the data.  What is your code you are using?

Comment: `// Ship example
$ship_Ret = $fed->ship_express($ship_data);

if ($error = $fed->getError()) {
    echo "ERROR :". $error;
} else {
    // Save the label to disk
    $fed->label('mylabel.png');
}`